# Windows Phone 8.1: DependencyProperty callback method fired just once (until the value is changed, NotifyPropertyChanged is triggered)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, dependency-properties, caliburn.micro, behavior

I have registered this behavior in the Windows Phone 8.1 app (not SilverLight):

```
public class MessageBoxDisplayBehavior : DependencyObject, IBehavior
{   
    public string Message
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MessageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MessageProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MessageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Message", typeof(string), typeof(MessageBoxDisplayBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnMessageChanged)); 

    private static void OnMessageChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var msg = e.NewValue as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(msg))
        {
            //this is fired only once, even if I call 
        }
    } 
}
```

The Xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="Client.Views.PageViewBase"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Client.Views"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:behaviors="using:Client.Behaviors"
    xmlns:i="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:MessageBoxDisplayBehavior Message="{Binding MessageBoxMessage}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Page>
```

The view model inheriting from Caliburn.Micro Screen

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : Screen
{
    public string MessageBoxMessage
    {
        get
        {
            return _messageBoxMessage;
        }
        set
        {
            _messageBoxMessage = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MessageBoxMessage);
        }
    }
    private string _messageBoxMessage;
}
```

The thing here is, that when I set the property *MessageBoxMessage* in viewmodel to the value *"test"*, the method *OnMessageChanged* of the *MessageBoxDisplayBehavior* class is triggered. It's ok.

But when I set it to the value *"test"* again, the method *OnMessageChanged* is not fired again (but notify property changed has been triggered, I can subscribe to the *PropertyChanged* event and catch it).

It gets working again when I set the value to something else (e.g. *"test2"*).

Is the dependency object holding the property's value internally and triggering the change only when it does change? Can I overwrite it somehow?

I want the DependencyProperty callback method get fired when the NotifyPropertyChanged is called, even if the value is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

The property doesn't change if you reassign the property the same value "test".

It will change if you continue to assign it different string values.

Remember, it's **"property changed"**.

In your case, you're not changing the value. You just keep submitting the same value expecting a different result.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I'm not changing it, but I have triggered the PropertyChanged event by *NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MessageBoxMessage);* so it should be enough, shouldn't it?

Comment: Try viewing the implementation of that method and check if they cache the last value and then execute the update on comparing the present value to the last value. My guess is they are performing the same validation that your code should be doing but doesn't.

Comment: Yes, exactly, they are I guess. But which one method? It's done probably somewhere inside the DependencyProperty object..

Comment: idk... But please mark my answer if this information answers your question.